# Stl c++ dynamic memory allocation

Tags: c++, stl, heap-memory

I came across some legacy code and I see this.

```
typedef std::queue < EventDataPair > EventQueue;
_eventQueue = new EventQueue();
```

Why would one want to use a stl Queue allocated on Heap???
The class containing this code is a Singleton.

To Generalise it, When should one allocate a stl on Heap???
STL's themselves are dynamic in nature, and they may use heap internally.

Furthermore, won't you have the overhead of deallocating it in the destructor??

Comment: For the same reason you'd dynamically create anything: to allow you to control its lifetime. Out of context, there's no way to tell whether there's a good reason for this particular object to be dynamic.

Comment: Controlling it's lifetime is a valid observation...But apart from that, I really cannot find any reason especially in a singleton...You know the object would never be de-allocated. Furthermore, you would have the overhead of destroying it in the destructor??

Comment: i dont think there is any overhead of destroying it, unless the overhead is writing additional codes like `delete _eventQueue;`?

Comment: Yes, i meant additional code..Unnecessarily bloating the source files

Answer (score 2):

Well, unless you want to share the particular object between different contexts in the code there isn't much incentive to allocate on heap.

However for some legacy architectures you might be concerned with the size of your stack.

Answer (score 1):

One reason I can think of, is to avoid overhead of creating a copy when returning it from a function.

However, this is not needed any more with C++ 11 and move semantics.

Have a look at [this example](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=2080042) that Bjarne Stroustrap is talking about.